How do I access a registered HttpClient service in a lambda implementation factory?
I've been trying to research this but have come up empty. I've been trying to use elements from other questions:
Using Factory Pattern with ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection
On IServiceProvider what are the differences between the GetRequiredService and GetService methods?
ASP.NET Core DI: Resolve same instance if scoped service is registered both as service type and implementation type
It's a little bit confusing and no one has an example that exactly matches what I'm attempting to accomplish.
I have code similar to the following:
Middleware.cs

public static IServiceCollection UseAPI(thisIServiceCollection services, string key, string username, bool test = false)
{
    services.AddHttpClient<ApiClient>(client =>
    {
        // ... setting BaseAddress based on test, adding auth headers, etc
    });
    return services.AddScoped<ApiClient>(x =>
    {
        var service = x.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>();
        var ApiClient client = new ApiClient(service);
        client.Configure(key);
        return client;
    }
}


Program.cs

services.UseAPI(_settings.Key, _settings.Username, _settings.IsTest);


ApiClient.cs

public class ApiClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
    private string Key;
    public ApiClient(HttpClient _httpClient)
    {
        httpClient = _httpClient;
    }

    public void Configure(string key)
    {
        Key = key;
    }
}


The Key value is used as part of the process of creating a signature of the content and so can't be added to the default headers. I can't seem to figure out how to get the key from the middleware. Of course I can inject configuration and get it that way, but that's not portable and I'm building this as a package so minimizing reliance on that would be ideal.

You are mixing up concepts. A middleware is a component used in a request pipeline, not for handling service dependencies like HttpClient. Please read more in docs about middleware and service registration in ASP.NET Core. Your problem seems to be solved in the first linked question in your post. If it still does not satisfy you, please add more details and describe clearly what the issue is.

Currently you are trying to register your ApiClient twice.
The services.AddHttpClient<ApiClient>() configures a HttpClient instance that is passed to the ApiClient constructor and adds ApiClient to your service collection. There is no need to the AddScoped call afterwards. See Typed Clients.
The AddHttpClient<TClient,TImplementation>(IServiceCollection, String, Func<HttpClient,IServiceProvider,TImplementation>) overload of HttpClient would work for your case:
services.AddHttpClient<ApiClient, ApiClient>((httpClient, serviceProvider) =>
{
    var apiClient = new ApiClient(httpClient);
    apiClient.Configure(key);
    return apiClient;
});

I would also consider the Options Pattern to inject the key (and other settings).
services.AddOptions<ApiClientOptions>()
    .Configure(options => options.Key = key);

services.AddHttpClient<ApiClient>(httpClientOptions =>
{
    // Configure HTTP Client
});

// or something like
services.AddHttpClient<ApiClient>((serviceProvider, httpClientOptions) =>
{
    var options = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ApiClientOptions>>();
    // Configure HTTP Client
});

public class ApiClientOptions
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
} 

public class ApiClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly string _key;
    public ApiClient(HttpClient httpClient, IOptions<ApiClientOptions> options)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _key = options.Value.Key;
    }
}

One more suggestion: This is DI service registration / configurations injection rather than middeware, so the method name AddApi is better suited than UseApi.

That is fantastic. Thank you very much. I'm still relatively new to the concepts at this layer so this will be super helpful. All the tutorials I ended up following were saying middleware, but the distinction makes a lot of sense.
